# jquery-ui hover effect on framework icons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use the built-in jquery-ui icons and have them change style when the user hovers over them.  But I only seem to be able to do this if they are contained within another element and that causes an annoying box to be drawn around them.

For example, this appropriately changes the style but it winds up putting a box around the image:

```
$(".help-button").hover (
  function() { $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-hover'); },
  function() { $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-hover'); }
);

<span class="help-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="display: inline-block;">
  <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-info' style="display: inline-block;"></span>
</span>
```

This has the correct image, but it doesn't change the style (same JavaScript as above):

```
<span class="help_button ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some more information or link a page to show your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery ui css using class "ui-state-hover" which has square background so it is appeared.

try this way

```
.ui-icon1 { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(css/redmond/images/ui-icons_6da8d5_256x240.png); }
.ui-icon-new1{ width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(css/redmond/images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png); }


<span id="abc">
    <span class="help_button ui-icon1 ui-icon-info" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
</span>


$("#abc").hover (
        function() { $(this).children().addClass('ui-icon-new1'); },
        function() { $(this).children().removeClass('ui-icon-new1'); }
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much; this is _almost_ perfect. However, it is specific to the Redmond theme.  And, perversely, the jquery icon images seem have different filenames in different themes.  Any idea how I can pick out the "default" set and the "hover" set for any theme?  (I'm using Django, if that helps.)

Comment: You can refer to the jQuery css file and figure out.